# php exec() & java send parameters

Tags: java, php, exec

I want to connect to java via php and print the result out in php. Now I want to send a parameter to java and return it to php to see how it works. How can I do this?
I have this code so far:

PHP:

```
exec("java jar/name.jar", $output);
print_r($output);
```

Java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(args[0]);
    }
}
```

The result is

```
Array ( )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do

```
exec("/full/path/to/java -jar jar/name.jar 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

because

- your PHP env probably doesn't have java executable defined in the path (and it shouldn't, either)
- jar files are executed with `java -jar`
- you'll want `2>&1` to be able to see error messages in the output (redirect from stderr to stdout)

Comment: third point was very useful without it some program do not $output anything, dont know why !

Comment: @AbhishekK because it prints the errors on stderr, and normally only stdout is captured, where normal output goes

Answer (score 1):

Your java program expects atleast one argument, but the php code doesn't give it, so change your

```
exec('java jar/name.jar', $output);
```

to

```
exec('java jar/name.jar some_value', $output);
```

Edit:

The reason why you got Array ( ) when you did not specify an argument is probably because the error's send by java are send to stderr, and $output only gets data from stdout

Comment: I did what you said but the array is also empty.

Comment: @bw2801 are you sure you got the java jar/name.jar part correct? it would mean that relative to your php file the file name.jar is in the map jar. The way I tested it was: create test.php and Main.java in the same directory with your code. run javac Main.java and run php test.php (test.php had exec('java Main some_value', $output);

Comment: the folder "jar" is in the same directory as the php file.

Comment: You can try to use php -a, this will open php in interactive mode, then type exec('java jar/name.jar some_value', $output); perhaps it'll give you some more information

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a RESTful design.  Put the Java program at a URL and read from the URL with PHP *file_get_contents()*.   Anything the Java program writes to the browser output stream will be visible in the PHP variable that is loaded by that function.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to integrate native Java code into your PHP application, the [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) may be able to solve that in a better way than having to go through exec()-ing java code.

Creating a small service for your Java functionality is however the preferred way to go, then exposing those features through a small web based API (with JSON as the exchange format preferably).