# How to make my Java program use image path from PHP?

Tags: java, php

I am a beginner in Java programming, which I need for a very important project now. 
I have made a web-based user interface in php and now I need to integrate the Java program onto the php to run on the back-end. But before that, I faced the following issues:

1. The java program is only able to read in a specific file.

   ```
   oImage = new FileInputStream(new File("<image path>"));
   ```
2. Is there any way where I can pass a variable containing the image path from the PHP file into the Java program?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear. You should show us your work. A piece of PHP and Java code. Also what do you mean "i need to integrate the java program onto the php to run on the back-end"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write a [public static void main](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/javaguide/java/nutsandbolts/main.html)-function and [read your console-input](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=309) (from PHP) - just [pass the image path as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902470/php-exec-java-send-parameters) and you're done

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class OurPaint {

    private BufferedImage paint;
    private int x = 5;
    private int y = 320;

    public OurPaint() {
        try {
            paint = ImageIO.read(new URL("path"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage getPaint() {
        return paint;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

This will load an image from a url, you can probably also use file reader.